# where can we find the healthcare dataset

Tags: data-mining, data-science-model

I'm researching Medical Data set on some diseases like tuberculosis,cirrhosis,chronic kidney disease with the columns of age, body mass index, cholesterol, glucose, blood pressure, and the like that.

I want to reach such a data set for my KDD and exploratory lesson. Because I want to make useful project prototype.

if you know any data set web site pls share me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs to Open Data SE https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

A few important points:

- patient-based health datasets are rarely publicly available because this is sensitive personal data and properly anonymizing datasets is costly. ML research on these questions often requires a collaboration with a health institution which has direct access to patients (not doable for a student project, it's very complex administratively).
- There are however a few exceptions of datasets which are public, such as the [diabetes dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/diabetes). To my knowledge this is the closest to what you're looking for.
- Even if you could find some data about the diseases you mention, don't assume that any feature will be a good indicator. For example tuberculosis is an infectious disease, it's very unlikely to be predictable from variables such as body mass index or cholesterol.

Answer (score 1):

As @Erwan stated in [his answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/100135/84891), medical data is not easily accessible. However, during the pandemic a lot of data related to Covid19/SarsCov2 has been made available. Therefore, if you would like to focus on medical datasets I suggest to consider Covid19/SarsCov2 datasets, e.g. [see here](https://browse.welch.jhmi.edu/datasets/Covid19).

As a general note: When working with medical data it is important to understand the features and pathological mechanisms. Otherwise you might easily assume features to be predictive of an outcome which do not represent any causal relationship. Also, if you do not know how the data has been obtained you may easily make an error when interpreting a feature (e.g. for an ICD10-encoded diagnosis you need to understand how this diagnosis has been derived).

See, for example, [Common pitfalls and recommendations for using machine learning to detect and prognosticate for COVID-19 using chest radiographs and CT scans](https://www.nature.com/articles/s42256-021-00307-0). Similar issues can arise with tabular data.